# How 'Checkout for edit' works in TFS

Tags: tfs, tfvc, vcs-checkout

I need help to understand the working of 'Checkout for edit' in Team foundation server.

Right click on the Project/File --> Choose the option '**Check Out For Edit**'.

Help me to understand this option.

Comment: "Check out" is a term common to [version control systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control) (certainly for centralized models)

Answer (score 5):

When you want to edit a file you can open it from Solution Explorer or from Source Control Explorer. When you begin editing a file, it is automatically checked out to you.

In rare situations (for example, you want to check out and lock the file to make sure your changes are checked in before changes from other team members), you might need to manually (right click -> check out for edit) check out (and optionally lock) an item.

***What is "lock"?***

When you press on "Checkout for edit" and "lock" you till get Lock type menu:

**Unchanged:** Do not apply a lock to the items.

**Check Out:** Prevent other users from checking out and checking in the items until you check in and unlock them.

**Check In:** Allow other users to check out the items you are checking out, but prevent them from checking in their changes until you check in your changes and unlock the items.

> **Important:** As a best practice, use the Lock type option with
>   discretion and notify your teammates why you are locking an item, and
>   when you plan to remove the lock.